# Adding new Bundle to Bundle Config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, bundle

In my `_Layout` page I have these scripts:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Scripts.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/moment-with-locales.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/moment.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/DayPilot/daypilot-all.min.js")
```

So instead of writing all of those out, I want to create a bundle:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/otherScripts").Include(
    "~/Scripts/Scripts.js",
    "~/Scripts/moment-with-locales.js",
    "~/Scripts/moment.js",
    "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js",
    "~/Scripts/DayPilot/daypilot-all.min.js",
    "~/Scripts/DayPilot/daypilot-common.src.js"));
```

So now in my `_Layout` page I have this:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/otherScripts")
```

Now in my `bootstrap-datetimepicker.js` I have edited 1 line.. and the change shows visually when I test this app locally.. but when I publish.. that line that I changed does not work..

The only way it works is if I exclude the `bootstrap-datetimepicker.js`file from the bundle and reference it in the `_Layout` page specifically.

How do I just combine all of those scripts into the bundle and it work properly when published?

Comment: Have you verified this is not an issue with caching (i.e. hard refresh/open in incognito)?

Comment: I am clearing cache every time I exit out of IE.. I have tested this in Chrome as well and the same issue applies

Comment: Run your app, open the page in the browser and Inspect the element. Do you see the include for the `bundles/otherScripts` on your page?

Comment: @EugeneKomisarenko yes, I see this: `<script src="/Project/bundles/otherScripts?v=pkjl9HywKwfg_JF71H9oXv7fXoPNucCbPVXJBmRJQrE1"></script>`

Comment: When you open the source code of this script in browser, do you see the module you are looking for?

Comment: @EugeneKomisarenko I can't open the source code of the script in the browser.. i can only see the reference to the bundle.. but I can open the script in notepad on the server it was published to.. and the line that I changed is correct

Comment: Here is how you debug JavaScript in Chrome for your reference https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/reference. You can also enable formatting in the bottom left corner of the source code viewer. Add break point there or console.log to see if your code is actually executing

Comment: Are you publishing the site or just the file? If you're publishing just the file then the app may continue to serve the minified bundle it has created, ignoring your change. If the app restarts then it rebuilds the bundle.

Comment: @ScottHannen I am publishing the entire site.